Database Custom Remember Me Persistence Token Not Persisting Token
I did some spring boot web application using JSP and Spring security and so far is working fine. However I developed this for my mother and I need this site to never log out (or at least expire the session in one year) so it can be more comfortable for her. The issue was, every time she closes the browser(chrome) session was restarted.
I was checking last night and found that I can create a token when mom logs in and persist it to database so I spent all night trying to get Spring Security save a token session in database so the user can persist her user for next day. I've used several references since there are some old Spring framework methods no longer supported. I don't know where else to look so I'll post relevant part of code and configuration here so maybe you can recommend some changes.

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {




    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(rememberMeFilter(),RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean()).
                authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers( "/WEB-INF/jsp/**","/ofiweb/css/**",
                                "/ofiweb/img/**","/ofiweb/lib/**",
                                "/css/**",
                                "/mimg/**","/msass/**","/mjs/**",
                                "/mcss/**",
                                "/img/**","/lib/**"

                               ).permitAll()

                        .requestMatchers("/_ofiwebadmin/**").hasAnyAuthority("ROOT","OFFICE_ADMIN")

                        .requestMatchers("/creditcards/discounts", "/configuration/sftp").hasAnyAuthority("ROOT", "OFFICE_ADMIN")

                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                ).csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .rememberMe(rememberMe -> rememberMe
                        .key("Changed :P:P")
                        .tokenValiditySeconds(31536000)//1 Year if possible
                        .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
                        .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
                        .userDetailsService(userDetailService())
                        .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices())
                        .alwaysRemember(true)



                )
                .formLogin((form) -> form
                        .loginPage("/login").
                        permitAll()

                )
                .logout( logout -> logout
                        .logoutUrl("/logout")

                        .permitAll() );
                //.logout((logout) -> logout.deleteCookies("SESSION"));


        return http.build();
    }


    @Bean
    public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter()
            throws Exception {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter filter =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setRememberMeServices(rememberMeServices());
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    public OWAuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean(){
        return new OWAuthenticationManager();
    }


    @Bean
    RememberMeAuthenticationFilter rememberMeFilter() {
        RememberMeAuthenticationFilter rememberMeFilter = new RememberMeAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManagerBean(),rememberMeServices());
    //    rememberMeFilter.setRememberMeServices(rememberMeServices());
    //    rememberMeFilter.setAuthenticationManager(theAuthenticationManager);
        return rememberMeFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserService userDetailService(){
        return new UserService();
    }
    @Bean
    PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices rememberMeServices() {
        PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices rememberMeServices = new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices(getKey(), userDetailService(), persistentTokenRepository());
       // rememberMeServices.setUserDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
       // rememberMeServices.setKey("springRocks");

        return rememberMeServices;
    }

    @Bean
    RememberMeAuthenticationProvider rememberMeAuthenticationProvider() {
        RememberMeAuthenticationProvider rememberMeAuthenticationProvider = new RememberMeAuthenticationProvider(getKey());

        return rememberMeAuthenticationProvider;
    }




    @Bean
    public String getKey(){
        return "NotMyRealKey:P:P";

    }



    @Autowired private Environment env;

    @Bean(name = "persistentTokenRepository")
    public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
        JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl tokenRepository = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
        tokenRepository.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return tokenRepository;
    }
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("mysql.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}



public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(OfiwebApplication.class);
    }



}


@Component
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

  
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        //search username in database
        User byUsername = repository.findByUsername(username);

        if (byUsername == null || !byUsername.isBlocked())
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("USer not found: "+username);


            GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(byUsername.getRole().name());

            Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
            boolean add = authorities.add(authority);


            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(

                    byUsername.getUsername(),
                    byUsername.getPassword(),
                    authorities


            );


        }

}




public class OWAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        String username = authentication.getPrincipal() + "";
        String password = authentication.getCredentials() + "";


        User user = repository.findByUsername(username);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("1000");
        }
        if (!passwordEncoder().matches(password, user.getPassword())) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("1000");
        }
        if (user.isBlocked()) {
            throw new DisabledException("1001");
        }


            List<UserRole> userRights = new LinkedList<>();
            userRights.add(user.getRole());
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, userRights.stream().map(x -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(x.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList()));



    }

    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}


#DEV Server
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
mysql.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
server.port=8025
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
server.servlet.session.persistent=true
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
server.error.path=/error



      <form class="form-login" method="POST"  action="/login">
        <h2 class="form-login-heading">Inicio de Sesion</h2>
        <div class="login-wrap">
          <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" autofocus>
          <br>
          <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Clave">
          <label class="checkbox">
         &emsp;&emsp;   <input type="checkbox" name="remember-me" checked value="remember-me"> Recordarme en este equipo
            <br><br>
            <span>
<c:if test="${not empty loginError}">
<div class="alert alert-danger"><c:out value="${loginError}" /></div>

 </c:if>
            </span>
            </label>
          <button class="btn btn-theme btn-block"  type="submit"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i>Iniciar Sesion</button>
          <hr>

          <div class="registration">
           Si no tienes una cuenta, contacta a los administradores para que te faciliten una.<br/>

          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <!-- modal -->
      </form>
    

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login(ServletRequest request, Model model){

        Map<String, String[]> paramMap = request.getParameterMap();

        if (paramMap.containsKey("error"))
        {
            model.addAttribute("loginError", "Usuario o Clave incorrecta. Intenta nuevamente.");
        }



        return "login-ow";

    }

Link to log
Thanks in advance.
So far I've tried the following:

Using Redis for cache the session
Trying Http session timeout on properties files
Checking if some permission is needed from Browser end.


you are overcomplicating A LOT of stuff here, when you select formLogin, and define a UserDetailsService, spring will automatically setup UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, AuthenticationManager so i have no idea why you are implementing stuff that will be set for you? spring security is a framework, use the framework, read the docs

Agreed. Those verbose and redundancy is due to my tries last night. Still I could not make it using framework help. Thanks for your response.
